# Like operation selecting only one row in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I'm working on `SQLite` and I want use the `LIKE` operation in my query and i've used following query

```
SELECT * from TBL_words where words Like "%ab"
```

I've more than 10 words which are ends with **ab** but I'm getting only one word. Am I doing anything wrong? please any one suggest the solution for this, Thanks

Comment: How are you reading the results of your query?

Comment: Are you running the query in the sqlite console, or running it via a library?

What are the results if you run:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBL_words where words Like "%ab" `

Comment: I'm just using mozilla SQLite manager tool to see the result

Comment: @Zenox the count is 1. I'm using the mozilla SQLite manager tool excute the query.

Comment: Any trailing whitespace in the words that are not matched? Try with `... where trim(words) like '%ab'`

Comment: @RajPatil how many rows are in the table total? Could you past some of the words that are missing but you expect to see? What if you change your query to be `SELECT * from TBL_words where TRIM(words) Like "%ab"`   (specifically with the trim, incase there are whitespace characters after the ab).

Comment: @laalto yeah there are white spaces sorry for troubling you guys, I Imported from CSV file so i couldn't figure it out. Thank a lot

Comment: @Zenox yeah i had white spaces thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE '%ab'` will match columns that end exactly in the chars `ab`. Based on comments you have additional trailing whitespace in some of your `words`. You can use `TRIM(words)` in SQL to remove it.